# Background image on div isn't rendering

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to apply a simple background image to a div. It seems like such a simple problem but after hours of searching through many threads on Stack and other sources, and trying many of the solutions, i'm still looking at an empty div.

I've verified that the asterisk.png file exists and renders when called by itself from an  tag.

Here is the HTML

```
  <div class="element"></div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.element{
  background-image: url('images/asterisk.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Im hoping someone can point out the simple error I'm making here ... Thanks!

Comment: What are the image's dimensions?

Comment: To make sure CSS I'm having trouble with I often toss in a border I can see. If you don't see that the page isn't seeing your CSS

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/b1e4825s/. Are you sure you have the proper path to your image?

Comment: also check the network tab in developers tools in your browser whether your image is even loading.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console? If not, can you host your image on imgur or something so we can see?

Comment: By default, the `background-size` property is rendered as `auto`, with the image's full dimensions. By the file's name I assume it is an image of an "asterisk", so if it is larger than 400x50 it may be easily missed... Try setting a `background-size` value such as `cover` and see if it helps

Comment: Are you referencing an external stylesheet? Is your css file located in a /css/  folder?  If so you will need to change the path to be relative to the css directory.  

     background-image: url('../images/asterisk.png');

Answer (score 0):

It should work, check in inspector if any other styles are not added to this element.
Something may make your element `display: inline` in this case, yes BG will be not visible, change it to display `block` or `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was incorrectly linking to the image file. 'images/asterisk.png' vs '../images/asterisk.png'.

My apologies ... I guess I had been staring at the screen for way too long and just needed to rest!

Thanks everyone.